# Why do we use "if( !class_exists )" in PHP?

Tags: php, class

Sorry, one stupid question here. I got a code from a developer and I don't much about Class or PHP so I'm trying to study. He wrote something like this and made me curious.

```
if( !class_exists('My_Class') ) :
class My_Class {
```

Can't we just only declare class like this?

```
class My_Class {
```

Why should we check the class exists eventhough we know there is no class?

Comment: If you declare a class that already exists you will get a warning error. Ideally classes should always be captive in namespaces to minimise such issues.

Comment: If you know that there is no class with the same name, then you shouldn't use `class_exists()`. Creating functions or classes inside if-statements can actually lead to side effects (since they can't be parsed/created before the code itself is executed since PHP won't be able to determine if the class should be created or not until then)

Comment: It definitely is a code smell. Check out the PSRs, they contain a few guidelines in particular on autoloader setup, which should possibly make this code obsolete.

Comment: Thank you all. I learned a important thing today.